# Spring STOMP Websockets: any way to enable permessage-deflate on server side?

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I'm working with spring-websockets under the spring-boot-starter 1.3.1.RELEASE, with the Jetty backend.  I am wondering how to enable permessage-deflate in the server.

I have a client hosted on a version of Firefox that is willing to negotiate the compression, ie the initial handshake to the WebSocket endpoint includes the compression negotiation header, like:

```
GET https://my-websocket-host/my-endpoint
...
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: v10.stomp,v11.stomp
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ...
...
```

, but the server response does not include the permessage-deflate extensions header in the upgrade response, meaning it is not willing to negotiate compression.  I have gone on a scavenger hunt for where this could be enabled in configuration but have not found anything.  Is there some API I can use to turn this feature on, or is it not supported in the current product?

Thanks very much,

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature needs to be enabled in Jetty itself, as I believe this extension is not registered by default. Spring provides a way to configure the handshake handler and enable that extension.

The principle is explained in [the reference documentation on websocket server configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-runtime-configuration), but here's a complete example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // make sure to use the handshake handler we've defined
        registry.addHandler(echoWebSocketHandler(), "/echo")
                .setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler()).withSockJS();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {

        WebSocketServerFactory factory = new WebSocketServerFactory();
        // add the "permessage-compress" Websocket extension
        factory.getExtensionFactory()
               .register("permessage-compress", PerMessageDeflateExtension.class);
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(factory));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I was hunting on the Spring side and not in the actual engine.

Comment: Hello! Could you please explain what is *echoWebSocketHandler()* ?

Comment: In that case, it's just any websocket handler; this is not relevant to the current question.