# Spring Websocket Configuration: using WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport and WebSocketConfigurer together - how?

Tags: spring, websocket, jetty, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I am configuring currently my Spring Websocket using the class

```
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport
```

now I came across the advice    [Spring STOMP Websockets: any way to enable permessage-deflate on server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347077/spring-stomp-websockets-any-way-to-enable-permessage-deflate-on-server-side)

that makes use of

```
public class SampleJettyWebSocketsApplication implements WebSocketConfigurer
```

and overrides

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry)
```

and  offers

```
@Bean
public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler()
```

Question, what is the relation between **WebSocketConfigurer** and **WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport**? In other words, can I possibly somehow add configuration from WebSocketConfigurer implementation via API of the first class, WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport, so all configuration remains in one single file?

Comment: Can you tell us why `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` isn't enough for you?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I am just a bit weak in the whole plethora of your objects :)) What I need is to enable permessage-deflate (see link in the question). I also override OutgoingExecutorChannel because we need strict sequencing in multithreading send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport` implementation is `DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration` which is configured via `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`. All you need in your custom code is `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` implementation. And that one is injected into `DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration`:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
public void setConfigurers(List<WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer> configurers) {
```

This is a sample config from my test-cases:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
static class ServerConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy());
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler())
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://foo.com")
                .addInterceptors(new HandshakeInterceptor() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) throws Exception {
                        return request.getHeaders().getOrigin() != null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Exception exception) {

                    }

                })
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry configurer) {
        configurer.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you Artem, so to add permessage-compress from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347077/spring-stomp-websockets-any-way-to-enable-permessage-deflate-on-server-side I shall just borrow handshakeHandler from there, or there is a better way to set up "permessage-compress"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that feature. But since Brian has answered there to proceed via `getExtensionFactory()`, I think there is really no other way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help! :)